# Get one stable link for Multiple excel sheets with the same name from Google Drive into PowerBi

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, powerbi

On daily basis I am getting an attachment in email. Basically that attachment is an excel spreadsheet. I am pushing that spreadsheet to google drive folder `./attachments` using Microsoft Power Automate. The main purpose of pushing that spreadsheet into google drive is to load into PowerBi for Analytics purposes.
In PowerBi I am using the "Web" connector to import the file and it's working fine. The sample link is below.

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/2/d/1eBJR6wrcFrdjv4Lbf_Wq3MQOeUwBbgLw/export?format=xlsx`

The above link exports the file into powerBi and hence I can load data into PowerBi.

The problem is, on daily basis I am getting new file in drive and the Unique Id of the file is not same. In the above example the unique Id `1eBJR6wrcFrdjv4Lbf_Wq3MQOeUwBbgLw` will be different for the second file even though I am renaming the file with the same name using Microsoft Power Automate when pushing to Google Drive. eg: "PowerBi load file.xlsx". Is that possible that I can get a stable link for all the files with the same name?.

I have also shared the whole folder `./attachments` and tried to get the link of the file but that doesn't work. eg:

`https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1h1VuPtXfWflgIQw7ecMTwweoLblADscq/PowerBi Analytics file.xlsx/export?format=xlsx`

Any help, suggestions will be really appreciated.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goals as follows.

1. You want to retrieve the file IDs from a filename.
2. You want to retrieve the file IDs from a shared folder.

#### Answer for question 1:

In order to retrieve the file IDs from a filename, I think that the method of "Files: list" of Drive API can be used.

The endpoint is as follows.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=name%3D%27{filename}%27
```

- The search query is `name='{filename}'`.
- In this case, the API key cannot be directly used because the file list tries to be retrieved from the while Google Drive including the file. In this case, the access token is required to be used.

  - By this, I thought that your goal 2 might be suitable.

#### Answer for question 2:

In order to retrieve the file IDs from a shared folder, I think that the method of "Files: list" of Drive API can be also used. In this case, at least, the file list is retrieved from the shared folder. By this, the API key can be used.

The endpoint is as follows.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=%271h1VuPtXfWflgIQw7ecMTwweoLblADscq%27%20in%20parents&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

- The search query is `'1h1VuPtXfWflgIQw7ecMTwweoLblADscq' in parents`.
- In this case, the file list can be retrieved using the API key because the folder is publicly shared and the file list is directly retrieved from the publicly shared.

  - But, in order to use this, it is required to use the API key. Please be careful this.

#### Other pattern:

If you want to achieve your goal without the API key and the access token, I would like to propose to use the Web Apps created by Google Apps Script as a wrapper API. When this Web Apps is used, you can achieve above both goals without using the API key and the access token.

- The official document of Web Apps is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).
- The unofficial document of Web Apps including several sample situations is [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script).

#### References:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Search for files and folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files)